# "display table-cell" with different heights on different tags

Tags: html, css, css-tables

First of all, I'm using **Google Chrome 34** on **Mac**.

This is the **HTML**, everything seems right:

```html
<div class="toolbar">
  <button type="button" class="item">Item 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="item">Item 2</button>

  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

And this is my **CSS**... (ok, it's **SCSS**):

```css
.toolbar {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;

  .item {
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 40px;   /* <---------- */
    outline: none;
    vertical-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;

    &:last-child { border-right: 0; }
  }
}
```

You can see these codes in action on http://codepen.io/caio/pen/yFzvK.

[image: CodePen]

The mystery is that Item 1 and 2 (`button` tag) assume the correct height (`40px`), but items 3 and 4 (`div` tag) assume a greater height (`50px`).

Moreover, mysteriously elements with `div` tag are right aligned.

Can you help me understand why this happens? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Do you *have* to set a fixed height? It doesn't make for a very responsive layout...

Comment: @AymanSafadi hnnn, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with the solution. Please use below code.  Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ambarox/hh6hL/) Trial

**SCSS**

```
body { 
  padding: 50px; 
}

.toolbar {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  button,div{-moz-box-sizing: border-box;}

  .item {
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-width: 0 1px 0 0;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;

    &:last-child { border-right: 0; }

    button{
     height:40px;
     outline: none;
     padding:0;
     margin:0;
     width:100%;

    }
  }

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="toolbar">
  <div class="item"><button type="button">Item 1</button></div>
  <div class="item"><button type="button">Item 2</button></div>

  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item">Item 4</div>
</div>
```